# Numpy Load OverflowError: length too large

Tags: numpy, matrix, persistence, scipy

I have an algorithm that runs through a dataset and creates a scipy sparse matrix which in turn is saved using:

`numpy.savez`

and the file is open such as:

`open(file, 'wb')`.

The matrix can get a considerable amount of disk space (it took about 20 GB running for 30 days)

After that, those matrices are loaded into other applications such as:

```
file = open(path_to_file, 'rb')
matrix = load(file)
data = matrix['arr_0']
ind = matrix['arr_1']
indptr = matrix['arr_2']
```

For 10 days it worked fine.

When running for a dataset of 30 days the matrix was also successfully created and saved.

But when trying to load it I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/ubuntu/recsys/Scripts/Neighborhood/s3_CRM_neighborhood.py", line 76, in <module>
    data = matrix['arr_0']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 241, in __getitem__
    return format.read_array(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 458, in read_array
    data = fp.read(int(count * dtype.itemsize))
OverflowError: length too large
```

If I could successfully create and save the matrices shouldn't it be able to also load the result? Is there some overhead that is killing the loading? Is is possible to work around this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

From the notes on the just published [numpy version 1.8, release candidate 1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0rc1/):

> IO compatibility with large files
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Large NPZ files >2GB can be loaded on 64-bit systems.

So it seems you hit a known bug that has just been solved.